# How public data block storage get update when involving private channel in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I recently get interesting in Hyperledger Fabric. I come across the concept of a private channel. I seem to get the idea of how it works. However, I got stuck when considering the following scenario on basic money transactions between three parties.

[image]

If we consider the above case when Alice wants to send money to Blob in a private channel and then send the money to Sara over the normal use case. How the peer outside the channel then verify the balance of Alice if they don't have the information about Alice and Blob private transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two ways

- control this in chaincode level
- control this in client level

what you are trying to do is some data present in one channel need to appear in another channel

you can query other channel data in chaincode itself else query private channel data before you call to public channel

Remember one thing there is no a concept called private/public channel if an organization is not part of a channel then it will see that channel as a private channel by concept

Comment: So, the endorsing peers during the chaincode execution can query data from the other channel that they are not a part of. Assuming the chaincode it specifies to do that. Then, with that transaction flow, is it correct to say that the data only temporarily available on that stage only for a peer which is not part of the channel?

Comment: Oh, You did not tell about peers and which peer belongs to which channel

Comment: If peers are not part of the channel then it cannot able to get the data because every channel has its own ledger. Peers must be present in both channel then only it will work

Comment: In the case that you said any peer could not in any way get data from other channels that they do not belong to. How would the system later reach a consensus on the transaction between Alice and Sara as in the case of the figure above, some peer will not know about the transaction between Alice and Bob. This will lead to a different ledger for some peers. Am I correct?

Comment: you need to understand one thing that channels are separate chains, means totally separate ledger

Comment: Okay, correct me if I am wrong, in the above case, Alice would have to have two different balance account to do that transaction, right? Because Alice belongs to two different channel, let say and the system has to maintain two different ledgers.

Comment: My assumption for the above case is that all of them have only one balance account when they perform the transaction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201647/discussion-between-narendranath-reddy-and-makarapr).